# I am creating a game tool using classes and functions. I need to store the game info in an index of an array but dont know how?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class

```
//Amanda Genise
//CSC123 - Part 3
//08/06/2015

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class gamelist
{
private:
    int gamecount;
    //gameobject gameobjs[10];

public:
    void add_game();
    void print_list();
    float total_value();

};

class gameobject
{
    public:
        void set_id_num(int num);
        int get_id_num();
        void set_name(string name1);
        string get_name();
        void set_type(int type_of_game);
        string get_type();
        void set_buy_value(float buy_game);
        float get_buy_value();
        void set_market_value(float market_price);
        float get_market_value();
        void set_year(int year1);
        int get_year();

    private:
        int id_num;//identifier number for the game
        string name;//the name of the game
        int type;//whether the game is cartridge, CD, DVD, BR, download
        string type_name;//type of game
        float buy_value;//price of game
        float market_value;//value of game
        int year;//year the game was made
};

int main()
{
    int option;//menu choice

    do
    {
        //menu
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please choose an option from the below menu. " << endl;
        cout << "1. Add Game" << endl;
        cout << "2. Print List" << endl;
        cout << "3. Total value of collection" << endl;
        cout << "4. Delete Game" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Which would you like to execute? ";
        cin >> option;
        cin.ignore();

        //to add a game
        if (option == 1)
        {
            gamelist run;

            run.add_game();
        }

        else if (option == 2)
        {
            gamelist run;

            run.print_list();

        }

    } while (option != 5);

    if (option == 5)
        return 0;
}

void gamelist::add_game()
{
    gameobject test;
    int id;
    string name_game;
    int type_game;
    int buy;
    int market;
    int year_game;

    cout << "Please enter an id number for the game: ";
    cin >> id;

    test.set_id_num(id);//passes value

    cout << "Please enter a name for the game: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name_game);

    test.set_name(name_game);//passes value

    cin.ignore();
    cout << "There are four types of games." << endl;
    cout << "     0. Cartridge " << endl;
    cout << "     1. CD " << endl;
    cout << "     2. DVD " << endl;
    cout << "     3. BR " << endl;
    cout << "     4. Download " << endl;

    cout << "Which type do you want to set for the game (enter number)? ";
    cin >> type_game;

    test.set_type(type_game);//passes value

    cout << "Please set a buying value for the game: ";
    cin >> buy;

    test.set_buy_value(buy);//passes value

    cout << "Please set the market value of the game: ";
    cin >> market;

    test.set_market_value(market);//passes value

    cout << "What is the model year of the game? ";
    cin >> year_game;

    test.set_year(year_game);//passes value
}

//sets id num for the game
void gameobject::set_id_num(int num)
{
    id_num = num;
}

//displays the id num for the game
int gameobject::get_id_num()
{
    return(id_num);
}

//sets desired name for game
void gameobject::set_name(string name1)
{
    name = name1;
}

//displays the name of the game
string gameobject::get_name()
{
    return(name);
}

//presents a menu to choose type of game
void gameobject::set_type(int type_of_game)
{
    type = type_of_game;
}

//prints the type of game chosen
string gameobject::get_type()
{
    if (type == 0)
    {
        type_name = "cartridge";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 1)
    {
        type_name = "CD";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        type_name = "DVD";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 3)
    {
        type_name = "BR";
        return(type_name);
    }
    else if (type == 4)
    {
        type_name = "download";
        return(type_name);
    }
}

//sets the buying value of game
void gameobject::set_buy_value(float buy_game)
{
    buy_value = buy_game;
}

//displays the buying value for game
float gameobject::get_buy_value()
{
    return(buy_value);
}

//sets market value
void gameobject::set_market_value(float market_price)
{
    market_value = market_price;
}

//displays market value
float gameobject::get_market_value()
{
    return(market_value);
}

//sets model year of the game
void gameobject::set_year(int year1)
{
    year = year1;
}

//displays model year
int gameobject::get_year()
{
    return(year);
}
```

I have not written the code for print or total value. But I am mostly worried about getting the gameobject gameobjs[10] array to work. I have no idea how to fill the array and it is supposed to be filled with the game info after I add a game. help?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the application to see what is going wrong?

Comment: yeah there is nothing really wrong with my code. I just don't know how to store the add_game info into an index of the gameobjs[10] array? I have to do that somehow. @JustAnotherDotNetDev

Comment: You could create a gameSettings object to store the settings set in the add_game method, then make gameSettings a child object of the gameObject?

Comment: could you demonstrate that? Like create a new set function? i am not sure how to do that with arrays @JustAnotherDotNetDev

Comment: From the sounds of it, if your teacher wanted it stored in an array then there is no real point of me demonstrating it. Nishant's answer should work for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh okay well I appreciate the response anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `void gamelist::add_game()`

```
test.set_id_num(id);

this->gameobjs[0].set_id_num(id);
```

Then what you can do is to execute the statements present in add_game() in a loop, and add 10 gameobjects.

Try this, it will help you to add 10 games for 1 `gamelist` object

```
    int id;
    string name_game;
    int type_game;
    int buy;
    int market;
    int year_game;
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    { 
    cout << "Please enter an id number for the game: ";
    cin >> id;

    this->gameobjs[i].set_id_num(id);
    cout << "Please enter a name for the game: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name_game);
    cin.ignore();
    this->gameobjs[i].set_name(name_game);

    cout << "There are four types of games." << endl;
    cout << "     0. Cartridge " << endl;
    cout << "     1. CD " << endl;
    cout << "     2. DVD " << endl;
    cout << "     3. BR " << endl;
    cout << "     4. Download " << endl;

    cout << "Which type do you want to set for the game (enter number)? ";
    cin >> type_game;
    this->gameobjs[i].set_type(type_game);

    cout << "Please set a buying value for the game: ";
    cin >> buy;
    this->gameobjs[i].set_buy_value(buy);

    cout << "Please set the market value of the game: ";
    cin >> market;
    this->gameobjs[i].set_market_value(market);


    cout << "What is the model year of the game? ";
    cin >> year_game;
    this->gameobjs[i].set_year(year_game);
    }
```

Comment: honestly thats how my teacher wanted it. I really have no idea it seems odd to me too and I am a beginner.

Comment: so if I do that and re ran the project again would it store the new info in a different index @nishant

Comment: no, it won't..... it will always store in first index, unless you explicitly specify or you can use loops to add multiple gameobjects in gamelist.
Your requirement is slightly unclear.

Comment: I am sorry i am supposed to be able to add up to ten indexes

Comment: so I have tried that and with a for loop but it is just repeating the add game function until the i get to the 10th index. Is there a way for this to run just once? @nishant

Comment: i am thinking my for loop is not in the correct place.